TraceId and SpanId are not getting printed while using micrometer with spring boot
Trying to use micrometer for monolith application for tracing purpose but it is not appending traceId in logs.
I've used these in my pom.xml and spring boot version is 3.2.0 and java 21
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


If you are using Spring Boot, please do not define the Micrometer (Tracing BOM) version, let Boot define it for you (i.e.: delete micrometer-tracing-bom).
micrometer-tracing is also not needed, you will get it through micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave. At this point you might want to check https://start.spring.io and generate a sample project with the right dependencies.
Starting from Spring Boot 3.2.0, the traceId should be visible in your logs (before that you needed to set a property). If you double-checked that you are using Boot 3.2.0 with the right properties, and you still don't se tracing info in your logs I think two things could have happened:

You are emitting the log event from a section of code that it is not instrumented, you will not see tracing info (a span should be created and put it into scope). Try to emit a log event from a controller method or set the log level of DispatherServlet lower:

logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG


There is something wrong with your project setup that prevents auto-configuration to work, you can create a sample project using start.spring.io to check this (example).

